# Are there specific lawnmower spark plugs?

Tags: lawn-mower, tool-maintenance

My mower needs a new spark plug. It won't start and the plug is covered in crud. It has been cleaned a couple of times before so I think I will just go for new.

The spark plug model needed is NGK BPR6E.

My question is whether there are different spark plugs for cars and mowers? Or whether I can buy any BPR6E and it'll do the job?

I raise the question because, for example, Halfords site lists the same model number in both auto and gardening sections, in different packaging, but specs seem the same.

Comment: If it covered often with crud, check if there is a oil leak, or rusted tanks.

Comment: Normally it get's crudded up after several months of use, so I don't think there's a severe problem. Plus the manual suggests a new plug every 2 years and we're past that now.

Comment: Could you check better in the catalog. It should have an other letter (and possibly number) https://www.ngksparkplugs.com/assets/design_symbols_plugs.pdf

Comment: BTW if the size is ok, I think you can use on your lawnmower. I think car plugs are certified and possibly have better quality.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are different plugs for different engines. Usually you need the engine model on your mower, and take in the old spark plug to the hardware store. Ask for someone to help you find the right spark plug and tell them your engine model and mower model.

Usually near the spark plugs at the store there is a booklet showing your old model of spark plug and what model the brand in front of you is compatible with. If not, someone behind the counter might have that book. They get used and abused a lot.

Comment: As stated I do have the plug model number. It's more a question of whether there is a difference between the same part number which is marketed (in different packaging) in both auto and gardening applications,

Comment: No difference. The same spark plug model can be used in any application/engine that calls for it.